# Riddle of hot love

Tags: riddle

> On the upper side, you kiss me.
>
> In the middle, your fingers caress my body.
>
> And below is the burning flame of hot love.

It's definitely not something sexual anyone might be thinking.

What am I?

Comment: Nice riddle! Well done! $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are

> A Cigarette.

- On the upper side, you kiss me.

  > a cigarette is kept in the mouth in such a way that is as close as possible to kissing.
- In the middle, your fingers caress my body.

  > In the middle is where you hold a cigarette, with your fingers "caressing" the cigarette.
- And below is the burning flame of hot love.

  > the bottom is where the hottest part is, which glows more and more as you kiss(suck it) it more(this is love probably). And the more your "*love*" is, the hotter it gets.

Comment: Perfect answer. xD You're correct!

Answer (score 12):

> A cup of hot drink?
>  You touch the top of the cup of your lips (kiss)
>  You hold it somewhere in the middle
>  The  hot drink is in the bottom of the cup.

Comment: This one makes more sense to me than the designated correct answer, because it addresses the "top", "middle", and "below" aspects.

Comment: @AdmiralJota and so does the accepted answer...? I like both answers, but I do believe this one needs more upvotes ;)

Comment: @user477343 I tend to think of the accepted answer as being horizontal (at least, when in use, which is what the clues refer to), so "top" and "below" don't apply so well.

Comment: @AdmiralJota well, it doesn't say "top", but it says "upper side". Of course, since cigarettes are horizontal, they are on its *side*, and the upper part of a cigarette is its top part. But this looks like an excuse; moreover, "below" does not work well with describing a cigarette. But eh, the answer has been accepted. How would you have said the riddle (just curious)?

Comment: @user477343 Good question. Perhaps "the near side" and "afar" instead of "the upper side" and "below"? But that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: @Admiral Jota user477343 I'm sorry I can't really help it. I could've edited my question earlier, but for now, I found a picture of this guy vertically smoking a cigarette: [img1](https://previews.123rf.com/images/vadymvdrobot/vadymvdrobot1705/vadymvdrobot170501040/78168417-vertical-image-of-a-young-man-in-t-shirt-smoking-cigarette-and-writing-something-in-notebook-over-gr.jpg) And this one: [img2](https://previews.123rf.com/images/tverdohlib/tverdohlib1508/tverdohlib150800128/43376938-portrait-of-sexual-young-unshaven-man-with-beard-and-handlebar-moustache-smoking-cigarette-looking-f.jpg)

Comment: @문동선 I see... I never thought of it like that :P

Comment: @AdmiralJota I think perhaps you should look at the text two messages above this ;)

Comment: @user477343 If you mean the one with a Korean username, I think that might have already been deleted :\

Answer (score 11):

Are you a ...

> Pipe?
>  On top you (kiss?) smoke
>
>  In middle you hold a pipe
>
>  On top it's hot because ember

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer a

> Cuppa Joe?  Because, well, coffee is one hot beverage that inspires intense love.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! In the future, please put your answers in the ">!" format so as not to let other people see your answer unless they want too. Thanks for your answer - have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

I know there's an already accepted answer but...

Could it be a

> Marshmallow!

On the upper side, you kiss it

> You eat the marshmallow at the tip of the stick, and if it's hot enough, you can only "kiss" it with your lips.

In the middle, you caress it with your fingers

> That's where you gently hold the stick.

And below, the burning flame of hot love

> That's the lovely bonfire that allows you to prepare such a lovely snack.